# Linq clarification on projection

Tags: c#-4.0

This question is to seek technical help in projecting enumerables to meet specified condition.

Say,

A ball contains two Red balls and three Blue balls.Based on the following conditions i have to select the balls.

```
(i)  Each pair should contain one blue ball and one red ball
(ii) if the ball is "Blue1" ignore it
```

and the expected result is

```
{"Blue2","Red1" }
{"Blue2","Red2" }
{"Blue3","Red1" }
{"Blue3","Red2" }
```

Just i want to complete the following code to project the result.

```
var bag = new[] { "Red1", "Red2", "Blue1", "Blue2", "Blue3" };
var BallsProjection =
                 from blueball in bag
                 from redball in bag
                 **(What is the condition required here to select the balls)**
                 select new { ball1 = blueball, ball2 = redball };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the result what you wanted.

```
 var BallsProjection =
               from blueball in bag
               from redball in bag
               where 
               blueball.Contains("Blue") && redball.Contains("Red") && blueball.CompareTo("Blue1") !=0
             select new { ball1 = blueball, ball2 = redball };
```

You can enhance this code to meet your requirement.I have not tested this code.